# TinyMCE ignoring init options on submitting data

Tags: javascript, tinymce

got an odd issue here with tinyMCE.

What appears to be happening is that we have one or more instances of tinymce for multiple text areas on the page. For this debugging, we removed all but one instance so it is not getting confused with that and the problem is still persisting.

The problem is that when you load the page, configuration gets loaded correctly and I can see it in the debugger when we check verify_html, it is set to false as expected by the configuration. However when you use "edit html source" button, enter some sample data and click update, some tags get stripped out.

We are using the latest tinymce (3.5.8), I diffed what we use vs the one you can download and it is identical.

What I found so far was that when you initialsie tinymce and it comes to line 1964 (after using a js beautifier for debugging), it does this A = A || {}; So in the initial init, we get the correct options object for A. Where all the configuration parameters that we set are as expected and verify_html is set to false. Which in turn sets valid_elements to allow everything.

```
if (A.verify_html === false) {
            A.valid_elements = "*[*]"
```

This works fine, however when we enter some html and click update, when we come to this line object A is empty and does not contain any of the options that we set. Which means that some html get parsed out. Has anyone encountered this issue in the past?

I am not very familiar with tinyMCE, so would appreciate some help with this issue, including the stack trace and options configuration, but I am pretty sure it is not related to options as they do not appear to be being picked up at all when it comes to be checking if A exists.

For the stack trace, here is the trace during init:

```
f.html.Schema (tiny_mce.js:1964)
k.create.initContentBody (tiny_mce.js:9863)
k.create.init (tiny_mce.js:9832)
k.create.render (tiny_mce.js:9666)
a.dom.ScriptLoader.loadScripts.d.length (tiny_mce.js:7221)
c.each (tiny_mce.js:110)
a.dom.ScriptLoader.loadScripts.o (tiny_mce.js:7220)
a.dom.ScriptLoader.loadScripts.d.length (tiny_mce.js:7215)
p (tiny_mce.js:7117)
```

And stack trace during update to the text

```
f.html.Schema (tiny_mce.js:1964)
a.html.Serializer (tiny_mce.js:3358)
u (editor_plugin.js:1)
tinymce.create.objectToImg (editor_plugin.js:1)
tinymce.create.init.n.onPreInit.add.n.serializer.addNodeFilter.v (editor_plugin.js:1)
b.html.DomParser.f.parse (tiny_mce.js:3174)
k.create.setContent (tiny_mce.js:10372)
saveContent (source_editor.js:5)
onsubmit (source_editor.htm:33)
```

init config:

```
tinyMCE.init({

    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "editorunfiltered",

    dialog_type                       : "modal",

    urlconvertor_callback :         "myURLConvertor",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onPreProcess.add(function(ed, o) {
            if (o.node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "body")
                o.getInner = true;
        });
    },
    verify_html : false,
    relative_urls : false
});
```

Code I am trying to submit into tinymce:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AAAA-1111-2222-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="391" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="/imapbuilder/loader.swf" />
    <param name="base" value="/imapbuilder/" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="datasource=ambassadors.xml" />
    <param name="loop" value="false" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="quality" value="best" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/imapbuilder/loader.swf" width="391" height="600">
      <param name="movie" value="/imapbuilder/loader.swf" />
      <param name="base" value="/imapbuilder/" />
      <param name="flashvars" value="datasource=ambassadors.xml" />
      <param name="loop" value="false" />
      <param name="menu" value="true" />
      <param name="quality" value="best" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <!--<![endif]--><!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `verify_html` is not available anymore since version 3.3 .
You wil have to use the paramters `valid_elements` and `valid_children` to define what html code is valid and what is not.

Comment: Are you sure? It is both in code and listed in the config for tinymce.
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:verify_html

We definately have the latest version. At any rate I have tried passing in valid_elements in too, it had no effect.

If possible I be pointed to a function that deals with parsing of html so I can walk through it and find out more? I am a little lost as to where that one is.

By the way, thanks for the reply

Comment: it is listed, but not functional since version 3.3

Comment: Oh I see, I did use valid_elements before, both with *[*] and using the default and full xhtml rule sets that are listed in the manual but to no avail. Edited the original post to include the code I am trying to paste in.

The thing that is being filtered out is the classid and codebase attributes. Any ideas I can try to debug this problem further? @Thariama

Thanks for the replies by the way!

Comment: valid_elements = "*[*]" does not work because of a bug. can you create a tinymce fiddle?   fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/REcaab) So this is pretty much default, using default ruleset, which contains both classid and codebase attributes of object element.

From what I worked out with valid_children, I added the object. When you paste the code above, it still parses out both codebase and classid from object.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out miself, even though the settings i took did not work. I posted a question in the tinymce forum - lets see what they reply.